# Bitnami ownCloud 8.1.1-0 theme

Tags: bitnami, owncloud

I was trying to apply style changes like logo, header to my owncloud project.

From vm instances in compute Engine I could only see SSH and cannot see any files section / remote desktop option to replace any of the files to change the theme.

Any suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

If you need to upload any files (for example the theme's files or a logo) you can upload them using a SFTP client. Before connecting to your server, you have to download the keys using the Bitnami Launchpad for Google Cloud Platform dashboard. Then, you have to configure your client to connect to your server, you will use it the IP of your instance. You'll find more information about how to achieve that using this link:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Google_Cloud_Platform/Servers#How_to_upload_files_to_the_server_with_SFTP.3f

To modify the configuration files of your application you have to use the SSH console that you can easily launch using the dashboard. You can load the Bitnami console using the following command:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/use_owncloud
```

Then you can modify the files of ownCloud using an editor like vim, emacs or nano. You will find the files of ownCloud at `/opt/bitnami/apps/owncloud/htdocs/`. The config.php file is at `config` where you can set the theme that you want to use

```
'theme' => 'themename',
```

and the themes' files are at `themes`. You can modify the logo, colours, ... of your theme modifying the css files of it.

You will find more information about it using this link

https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/operations/theming.html

I hope it helps.
Jota